# deleting minikube cluster so I can create a larger cluster with more CPUs

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I need to run  sudo minikube start --memory=4096 --cpus=2 for my use case.  However it is running with 1 cpu already.  Somehow I started it w/o creating an entry in ~/kube/config
so "kubectl config delete-cluster minikube" returns, "error: cannot delete cluster minikube, not in /home/ec2-user/.kube/config".

Trying to work around this, to delete my cluster and start with a larger one, I ran, "kubectl config set current-context minikube".  Which created this entry in .kube/config:
cat .kube/config

apiVersion: v1

clusters: null

contexts: null
current-context: minikube

kind: Config

preferences: {}

users: null

NOTE: ignore double spaces I had to enter carriage returns to get the proper format)

Anyone know how to delete my current cluster, so I can create a bigger one with more memory and cpus?

Answer (score 10):

To change cpus or memory you want to get the profile name like mentioned before:

```
minikube profile list
```

And then delete the profile you want to change, in my case it was minikube:

```
minikube delete --profile minikube
```

Then you can start minikube again creating new profile:

```
minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox --cpus 8 --memory 16g
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to run `minikube stop`, then you should be able to start minikube again with more resources (`minikube start --memory=4096 --cpus=2`).

No need to delete your cluster.

Comment: That is the problem, minikube stop fails with minikube stop
  Profile "minikube" not found. Run "minikube profile list" to view all profiles.
  To start a cluster, run: "minikube start" and minikube start fails with minikube start --memory=4096 --cpus=2
  minikube v1.25.2 on Amazon 2 (xen/amd64)
✨  Using the docker driver based on user configuration

⛔  Exiting due to RSRC_INSUFFICIENT_CORES: Requested cpu count 2 is greater than the available cpus of 1

Answer (score 0):

I run `minikube` with `--driver=docker`and 1 cpu, using this command :

```
minikube start --driver=docker --extra-config=kubeadm.ignore-preflight-errors=NumCPU --force --cpus 1
```

So if I want to delete minikube and all its files, I use those two commands:

```
minikube stop

minikube delete --all=true --purge=true
```

then you can run minikube with your specifications :

```
minikube start --memory=4096 --cpus=2
```